# Define variable as output of boots package bootstrapping code

Tags: r

I would like to use the boots package and estimate the upper and lower confidence interval for my data (randomly generated here).

```
install.packages(c("boot"))

Zero_Fire_D <-rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1)

#Bootstrapping for 95% CI No Fire
library(boot)    #load the "boot" R package

mean1 <- function(Zero_Fire_D, i) {mean(Zero_Fire_D[i])}   #define custom function to calculate the mean

#perform bootstrap resampling of your data
boot1 <- boot(data = Zero_Fire_D, statistic = mean1, R = 2000) 
#x = your data, statistic = what statistic you want to calculate from your data,
#and R = number of bootstrap samples/replicates
#can do lots of types of bootstraps with the "boot" function
#(nonparametric, ordinary bootstrap is the default)

#calculate confidence intervals from your bootstraps
boot.ci(boot1, conf = 0.95, type = "perc")     #”perc” = percentiles

lower_confint <- 
upper_confint <-
```

How should I define variables: "lower_confint" and "upper_confint" to give them the values seen under "Percentile" and in the parenthesis in the image below (in this case, lower = 9.771, upper = 10.145)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a best practices suggestion: Use `set.seed()` when creating examples for simulation. Then assign the results of an operation to a named value, my choice, `res`. Then look at the value, which bears minimal resemblance to the console result. Use either `dput()` or `str()` for this purpose. Then you should see that the 4th and 5th elements of the item named "percent" is the same as your desired lower and upper "confint":

```
> set.seed(12345)
> Zero_Fire_D <-rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1)
> mean1 <- function(Zero_Fire_D, i) {mean(Zero_Fire_D[i])}   
> boot1 <- boot(data = Zero_Fire_D, statistic = mean1, R = 2000) 
> res <- boot.ci(boot1, conf = 0.95, type = "perc")     #”perc” = percentiles
> res
BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
Based on 2000 bootstrap replicates

CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = boot1, conf = 0.95, type = "perc")

Intervals : 
Level     Percentile     
95%   (10.03, 10.46 )  
Calculations and Intervals on Original Scale
> dput(res)
structure(list(R = 2000L, t0 = 10.2451971964548, call = boot.ci(boot.out = boot1, 
    conf = 0.95, type = "perc"), percent = structure(c(0.95, 
50.03, 1950.97, 10.0301855458532, 10.4626579205793), .Dim = c(1L, 
5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("conf", "", "", "", "")))), class = "bootci")
> str(res)
List of 4
 $ R      : int 2000
 $ t0     : num 10.2
 $ call   : language boot.ci(boot.out = boot1, conf = 0.95, type = "perc")
 $ percent: num [1, 1:5] 0.95 50.03 1950.97 10.03 10.46
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "conf" "" "" "" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "bootci"
> format(res$percent[4:5], signif=2)
[1] "10.03019" "10.46266"

> print(res$percent[4:5], digits =4)
[1] 10.03 10.46

lower_confint <- res$percent[4]
upper_confint <- res$percent[5]
```